# How to mock a constructor instantiated class instance using jest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, jestjs, mocking

Given a class `Person` that instantiates & uses another class `Logger`, how can the `Logger`'s method be verified to be called when `Person` is instantiated in the example below?

```js
// Logger.ts
export default class Logger {
    constructor() {}
    log(m: String) {
        console.log(m);

        // Other operations that are outside testing (e.g., file write).
        throw Error('error');
    }
}

// Person.ts
import Logger from "./Logger";
export default class Person {
    constructor() {
        const logger = new Logger();
        logger.log('created');
    }
    // ...
}

// Person.test.ts
import Person from "./Person";
import Logger from "./Logger";
describe('Person', () => {
    it('calls Logger.log() on instantiation', () => {
        const mockLogger = new Logger();
        getCommitLinesMock = jest
            .spyOn(mockLogger, 'log')
            .mockImplementation(() => {});

        new Person(); // Should call Logger.log() on instantiation.

        expect(getCommitLinesMock).toBeCalled();
    });
});
```

One option is to pass `Logger` as a constructor argument like below:

```js
class Person {
    constructor(logger: Logger) {
        logger.log('created');
    }
    // ...
}
```

However, is there any other way without changing the constructor to complete the test?

Comment: Are the classes defined in separate files or the same file?

Comment: The classes are in separate files, I'll update the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) and it will automatically mock all the exports from the given module.

So you can do `jest.mock("./Logger")` and the `Logger` constructor and all of its methods will get replaced with mock functions (*that return `undefined` by default*) and now you can spy on the behavior of the constructor and all of its methods.

```
import Person from "./Person";
import Logger from "./Logger";

jest.mock("./Logger");

describe("Person", () => {
  it("calls the Logger constructor on instantiation", () => {
    new Person();
    expect(Logger).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

All mock functions have a special `.mock` property where various data related to the mock function is available including the instances that the mock constructor function has created, when it was invoked with `new`.

So, all the instances created by the mock `Logger` are saved in `Logger.mock.instances` and you can use this to spy on the method calls.

```
import Person from "./Person";
import Logger from "./Logger";

jest.mock("./Logger");

describe("Person", () => {
  it("calls the Logger constructor and the log method on instantiation", () => {
    new Person();
    expect(Logger).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    const mockLoggerInstance = Logger.mock.instances[0];
    const mockLogMethod = mockLoggerInstance.log;
    expect(mockLogMethod).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Amazing, I didn't realize you could mock an entire class & it's methods by file with `jest.mock`. I'll accept this answer as it works & answers the question without changing the constructor :)

Comment: Is it also possible to use `jest.mock` to check specific methods like if `Person`'s constructor called `logger.method1` & `logger.method2`, how can `toHaveBeenCalled` be applied to those methods of the mocked `Logger` from the test?

Comment: So something like `Logger.method1.mockImplementation`? But that uses the static class where `method1` isn't available, I'm not sure how to access the instance method like `logger.method1.mockImplementation`

Comment: No, not like that because the method is not on the class itself it's on an instance of the class.

Comment: Good point, I'll open a new question :)

Comment: New question on instance methods here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72279428/how-to-mock-instance-methods-of-a-class-mocked-with-jest-mock

Answer (score 1):

Other way for test a class with method is use in mock the **prototype**.

```
import Person from "./Person";
import Logger from "./Logger";


jest.mock("./Person");

describe("Person", () => {

 it("mock and test Person method", async () => {

  jest.spyOn(Person.prototype, "somePersonMethod").mockImplementation(() => {
      return "testing Person class method";
   });
    
    //expect(...

 });

});
```

Comment: the ".prototype" saved me :)

Answer (score 0):

Given other answers, there's a typescript helper `jest.mocked`/`vi.mocked`, so a mocked instance can be easily cast like:

```js
vi.mock("./Person");

const mockedInstance = vi.mocked(new Person());
//mockedInstance.xxMethod.mockReturnValue(...)
```