# How to mock instance methods of a class mocked with jest.mock?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

How can the instance methods be mocked for a class that is being mocked with `jest.mock`?

For example, a class `Logger` is mocked:

```js
import Person from "./Person";
import Logger from "./Logger";

jest.mock("./Logger");

describe("Person", () => {
  it("calls Logger.method1() on instantiation", () => {
    Logger.method1.mockImplementation(() => {}) // This fails as `method1` is an instance method but how can the instance method be mocked here?
    new Person();
    
    expect(Logger.method1).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: have yout tried `import Logger from jest.mock("./Logger")`?

Comment: that gives the error `String literal expected`

Comment: Sorry, I meant  `const Logger =  jest.mock("./Logger")`

Comment: That makes sense but `Logger.method1` gives error `Property 'method' does not exist on type  '"./Logger"'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Automatic Mocking

Calling `jest.mock` automatically mocks all the exports from the module being mocked unless a manual mock is specified using the `__mocks__` directory.

So, this line `jest.mock("./Logger")` has automatically replaced the `Logger` constructor and all of it's methods with mock functions allowing us to test how these functions behave.

And the information related to the instances created by `Logger` is saved in `Logger.mock.instances`, so we can use this to test if the methods are being called properly.

```
import Person from "./Person";
import Logger from "./Logger";

jest.mock("./Logger");

describe("Person", () => {
  it("calls method1 on instantiation", () => {
    const p = new Person();
    // Logger constructor should have been called
    expect(Logger).toHaveBeenCalled();
    
    const mockLoggerInstance = Logger.mock.instances[0];
    const mockMethod1 = mockLoggerInstance.method1;
    // method1 should have also been called
    expect(mockMethod1).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

### Using Module Factory Parameter

You can also explicitly provide a module factory by passing in a factory function as the second argument to `jest.mock`. So, now the provided module factory would be used instead of Jest's automocking feature. Refer the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) for more information.

```
import Person from "./Person";
import Logger from "./Logger";

const mockMethod1 = jest.fn();
jest.mock("./Logger", () =>
  jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    method1: mockMethod1,
  }))
);

describe("Person", () => {
  it("calls method1 on instantiation", () => {
    const p = new Person();
    // Logger constructor should have been called
    expect(Logger).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // method1 should have also been called
    expect(mockMethod1).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

**Note:** `jest.mock()` calls are hoisted, so you cannot first define a variable and then use it inside a factory function unless the variable is prefixed with `mock`. And because of this we can access `mockMethod1` inside the factory.

### Manual Mock

You can achieve a similar behavior to module factory function by creating a manual mock located at `__mocks__/Logger.js`. And now this mock implementation can be used across test files by simply calling `jest.mock`.

```
// __mocks__/Logger.js
const mockMethod1 = jest.fn();
const mockLogger = jest.fn(() => ({
  method1: mockMethod1,
}));
```

Usage is similar to the module factory function but you now also have to import the mocked method in your test.

**Note:** You still need to use the original module path, don't include `__mocks__`.

```
import Person from "./Person";
import Logger, { mockMethod1 } from "./Logger";

jest.mock("./Logger");

describe("Person", () => {
  it("calls method1 on instantiation", () => {
    const p = new Person();
    // Logger constructor should have been called
    expect(Logger).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // method1 should have also been called
    expect(mockMethod1).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: accepting this answer as it looks like the correct way to mock the class - please can you also include a link to the documentation that explains using a factory function to return a default class & using `__esModule`?

Comment: I've added the link to the documentation in the answer, please check!

Comment: The docs explain it well, cheers!

Comment: Related question on mocking a specific method but keeping all others https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72280312/how-to-mock-a-specific-method-of-a-class-whilst-keeping-the-implementation-of-al